# using mplus for list of functions

Tags: haskell

In [Using the Maybe Monad in “reverse”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606228/using-the-maybe-monad-in-reverse) [acfoltzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204932/acfoltzer) nicely [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5606277/1866775) how to use [`mplus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v%3amplus). I want to have a similar effect but with the list of functions as a parameter:

```
tryFuncs :: [a -> Maybe b] -> a -> Maybe b
...
```

so a call like

```
tryFuncs [f, g, h] x
```

would become possible and do the same as

```
(f x) `mplus` (g x) `mplus` (h x)
```

How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to use `msum` (a list version of `mplus`) together with `map`:

```
tryFuncs fs x = msum $ map ($ x) fs
```

Comment: @larsmans `msum` uses `mzero` for the empty list, so that is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

(In the end, this solution will be identical to Ørjan Johansen's answer, since `Maybe`s `MonadPlus` is equivalent to the `First` `Monoid`'s behaviour. It's a neat little application of the `a -> b` monoid though, which is easily overlooked.)

Conceptually, the function you're looking for is ... `mconcat`!

```
tryFuncs' :: Monoid b => [a -> Maybe b] -> a -> Maybe b
tryFuncs' = mconcat
```

Unfortunately, the default `Monoid` instance for `Maybe` is not what you want here ("ignore `Nothing`, `mappend` `Just` contents"), otherwise that solution would have been truly neat.

But there's the `First` wrapper around `Maybe` that gives you the "retain first `Just`" behaviour, so that

```
-- newtype First a = First (Maybe a)
tryFuncsFirst :: [a -> First b] -> a -> First b
tryFuncsFirst = mconcat
```

What's left for you is to wrap/unwrap the `Maybe`s to `First`s.

```
firstify :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> First b)
firstify f = First . f

firstifyList :: [a -> Maybe b] -> [a -> First b]
firstifyList = map firstify

getFirst :: First a -> Maybe a -- Defined in Data.Monoid
```

So now you can recover your desired function by wrapping-mconcat-unwrapping,

```
[a -> Maybe b] -> a -> Maybe b
tryFuncs fs x = getFirst (mconcat (firstifyList xs) x)
```

But how does this work? Well, there are two monoids at work here, `First a` and `Monoid b => (a -> b)`, and the latter one is where the magic happens. To spell the instance out a little, using `<>` for `mappend`,

```
(a <> b) x = a x <> b c
-- and therefore
mconcat [a,b,c] x = mconcat [a x, b x, c x] -- (1)
```

So now the above code can be understood:

1. `First`-wrap all the input functions to take them from `a -> Maybe b` to `a -> First b`, which is the same, but has a different `Maybe` `Monoid` instance.
2. `mconcat` the list of functions, this uses the `Monoid b => (a -> b)` instance I just mentioned. All functions in the created list are applied to `x`, leaving you with a list of `First b`, which is then concatenated again, just as in (1).
3. Extract the resulting `Maybe` value out of the `First` wrapper again.